# GraphQL QueryResolver is giving ambiguity error

Tags: java, graphql

We are using a model with name **Process** in graphql api. while building the manifest, we are getting ambiguity error like below.

*QueryResolver.java:[12,20] reference to Process is ambiguous from both classes com.*.Process and java.lang.Process.*

How can I explicitly mention the QueryResolver to use the java.lang.Process in the below methods ?

'''
@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
java.util.List Process(ProcessInput input,graphql.schema.DataFetchingEnvironment env) throws Exception;
'''

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: @sp00m actually it's a custom library to our company, but in any library is there any parameters to resolve the imports while generating code ?

Comment: graphql-codegen-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0):

The following **customTypeMapping** tag solved my issue, We need to specify what type compiler need to use in runtime.

```
<customTypesMapping>
       <Process>com..schema.model.Process</Process>
</customTypesMapping>
```

You can find more details here

https://github.com/kobylynskyi/graphql-java-codegen/tree/master/plugins/maven